# Removing the escape characters from GNU Screen's screenlog.%n

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

Is it possible to remove the ESC sequences in GNU Screen's output file? Things such as colours, tabs and other escape characters make their way into the log files and become difficult to decipher.

I've tried Dr. Google & Co. as well as reading the manual, but haven't been able to find anything suitable...

Perhaps I've overlooked something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this piece of Perl magic:

```
perl -ne 's/\x1b[[()=][;?0-9]*[0-9A-Za-z]?//g;s/\r//g;s/\007//g;print' < screenlog.0
```

Comment: Thanks for that - that's AWESOME! It still has the ^G and ^M characters in there, but its a *lot* more readable...

Comment: Added that to the expression.

Comment: I wonder how many ASCII faces are in that one liner. I stopped counting around 20.

Comment: Of course I can write another one-liner that will count them.

Answer (score 15):

Also try the -r or -R option of less.

```
less -r screenlog.0
```

Comment: Nice solution. It deals with all the ^H (delete) characters properly, displays progress bars without the ^M cruft, and even preserves my color prompt! Of course, sometimes displaying a log isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

Use ansifilter.

```
ansifilter screenlog.txt > screenlog.txt.clean
```

Comment: is that something in every linux system or something that needs to be installed?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it's not even in the Ubuntu repos, so I'd say its not exactly popular. Looks like you have to get it yourself from the project page, and run/compile yourself. Wouldnt exactly call it a popular program http://ansifilter.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm on OSX and used `brew install ansifilter` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I don't know how this has changed since the 2012 comments about distribution, but I found this in the repo for the current release of Fedora (22).

Answer (score 6):

Once you capture your session in screenlog.n  , you can cat the file to the terminal and then use screen's hardcopy command to dump the cat's output to a file . The result will provide you with clean output that does not have any escape sequences.

The only 'gotcha' seems to be to make sure that hardcopy captures eveyrthing in the scrollback buffer and that the scrollback buffer contains only what you want to capture.

```
1. $ screen
2. $ cd /path/to/screenlog.n directory/
3. $ wc -l screenlog.n 
4. $ screen -X scrollback 245 # 245 is the number of lines found from your wc command + 5 
5. $ cat screenlog.n
6. $ screen -X hardcopy -h screenlog.n.cleaned
```

Note that  -h ensures that you capture the entire scrollback history and not just whats in immediate view

The screenlog.n.cleaned file will now contain a hardcopy of the cat output and won't include any escape sequences

Comment: Very very *neat*. All other perl/sed/python one-liner failed for me. Very frustrating when thinking that less -r/more were handling my file directly. One suggestion `wc -l` did not work for me. It returned 28226, but really needed 33031 in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I use the `strings` command to make a screen log readable. Under Debian it is part of the binutils package.

As its man page says:

> strings - find the printable strings
>   in a object, or other binary, file

Answer (score 2):

If you are `screen` user then the *screen hardcopy* solution suggested by [Joel 
Verks' post](https://superuser.com/a/185018/394294) will work best -- assuming that you have a large scrollback 
defined in your `.screenrc`:

```
defscrollback 10000
```

then you'd do:

1. Display your `screenlog` file:

   ```
   $ cat screenlog.<screen_window_num>
   ```
2. Use `hardcopy -h` (see screen man page) to save the current window content 
   and its scrollback buffer into the `hardcopy.#` file:

   ```
   <Escape key> (Ctrl-a by default)
   :hardcopy -h
   ```