# Convert shell logs (incl. escape characters) to HTML?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

Is there tool or a regexp that can convert shell escape characters to HTML code?

As an example, here is a logfile from GNU screen:

```
^MESC[K$ ^MESC[K$ exit
Executing .bashrc
ESC[00;31;31mserver.xyz.com: ESC[00;34;34m~
```

which I would like to convert to something like this:

```
$ exit
Executing .bashrc
<font color=red>server.xyz.com</font>: <font color=blue>~</font>
```

and send as HTML e-mail to an e-mail address, to archive my work.

Here is a [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/99128/removing-the-escape-characters-from-gnu-screens-screenlog-n), which shows how to convert it to regular text, but it would be nice to convert to HTML and not just throw the escape characters away.

Answer (score 1):

The query you need is [convert ansi to html](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&esrch=FT1&q=convert+ansi+to+html&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=).  [Here](http://search.cpan.org/~autrijus/HTML-FromANSI-1.01/) is a Perl package that seems to do it.